# using JAXB, the XML is loaded into a class. This class is then used within another class to be marshalled out differently

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

Given an XML file of offerings that is then loaded into a class called Offerings via JAXB.

This class has the following:
Name, Price sub-Class, Modifiers, Ordering Rules etc.

I then create an order and within that order

**Order**

```
public class ProductOrder {

    private String OrderId;
    private Date createDate;
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;
    private int CustomerOrderID;
    private ArrayList<ProductOrderItem> productOrderItems = new ArrayList<ProductOrderItem>();
}
```

**Order Item**

```
public class ProductOrderItem {
    private int OrderItemID;
    private **Offering** offering;
    private Map<String, Integer> qtylist = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private ArrayList<Modifier> modifiers = new ArrayList<Modifier>();
    private int qty;
}
```

**Offering**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "offering")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) // NONE) 
public class Offering {    
    @XmlAttribute
    private String id;

    @XmlElement
    private String offeringName;

    @XmlElement
    private String description;

    @XmlElement
    private Integer price;
}
```

The Offering and Modifiers are classes with JAXB already which I only want to push part of the XML.  How would I change the anotations such that only part of the elements are sent?  For example not the offering -> modifiers?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@XmlTransient` instead of the `@XmlElement` tag.

Comment: But I want BOTH. On receive, XMLElement and on the send XMLTransient would be my goal.

Comment: That case why not use separate VOs where transient attributes marked transient for out-bound marshalling?